# Caching PIN in multiple CMS Signatures

Tags: c#, cryptography, smartcard

Well, most of the questions/answers I've found here are regarding not caching a Smartcard PIN which is the opposite case of what I'm looking for.

We have a console application that signs multiple hashes. For this we use [Pkcs.CmsSigner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.cmssigner?view=netframework-4.8) because we need to validate the signed hashes server-side.

Normally a Smartcard's PIN should be cached automatically in the CSP per process and it does in Windows 7, but if we run our code in W10 it does not. Also we support both CNG and non-CNG certificates.

The method we use to sign is the following:

```cs
public string SignX509(string data, bool chkSignature, string timestampServer, X509Certificate2 selectedCertificate)
{

    CmsSigner oSigner = null;
    SignedCms oSignedData = null;
    string hashText = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        if (chkSignature)
        {
            oSigner = new CmsSigner();

            oSigner.Certificate = selectedCertificate;

            byte[] arrDataHashed = HashSHA1(data);

            // hash the text to sign
            ContentInfo info = new ContentInfo(arrDataHashed);

            // put the hashed data into the signedData object
            oSignedData = new SignedCms(info);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(timestampServer)) {
                oSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.Now));
            }
            else {
                TimeStampToken tsToken = GetTSAToken(arrDataHashed, timestampServer);

                AsnEncodedData timeData = new Pkcs9AttributeObject(Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.PkcsObjectIdentifiers.IdAASigningCertificate.Id, tsToken.GetEncoded());
                oSigner.UnsignedAttributes.Add(timeData);
                oSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(tsToken.TimeStampInfo.GenTime.ToLocalTime()));
            }

            // sign the data
            oSignedData.ComputeSignature(oSigner, false);

            hashText = Convert.ToBase64String(oSignedData.Encode());
            
        }
        else 
        {
            // just clean the hidden hash text
            hashText = String.Empty;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERRNO [" + ex.Message + " ]");
        return null;
    }

    return hashText;
}
```

### What we've tried so far:

1. **Using RSACryptoServiceProvider to explicitly persist the key in the CSP**

```cs
RSACryptoServiceProvider key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cmsSigner.Certificate.PrivateKey;
key.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
```

This works if we use the [SignHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signhash?view=netframework-4.8) method but as I've said before, we need to verify the signed data server-side and we do not have access to the certificate, therefore we need a PKCS envelope. If I set this bool and sign using the CMS code the behaviour is the same.

2. **Setting the PIN programmatically**

Another try was setting the PIN programmatically via CryptoContext, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786832/6248239):

```cs
private void SetPinForPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate, string pin) {

    if (certificate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
    var key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;

    var providerHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    var pinBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pin);

    // provider handle is implicitly released when the certificate handle is released.
    SafeNativeMethods.Execute(() => SafeNativeMethods.CryptAcquireContext(ref providerHandle,
                                    key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
                                    key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
                                    key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType,
                                    SafeNativeMethods.CryptContextFlags.Silent));

    SafeNativeMethods.Execute(() => SafeNativeMethods.CryptSetProvParam(providerHandle,
                                    SafeNativeMethods.CryptParameter.KeyExchangePin,
                                    pinBuffer, 0));
    SafeNativeMethods.Execute(() => SafeNativeMethods.CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
                                    certificate.Handle,
                                    SafeNativeMethods.CertificateProperty.CryptoProviderHandle,
                                    0, providerHandle));
}
```

With this approach **I am able to disable the PIN prompt by setting the PIN programmatically**. The problem here is that **I have to read the PIN** the first time so I can set it in the subsequent signatures.

I've tried to read the PIN from the prompt using [CryptoGetProvParam](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgetprovparam) with the dwParam PP_ADMIN_PIN and PP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN but without luck. My two guesses here are:

1. I'm not reading in the right time or way
2. CMS uses a different handler internally

---

### Question 1:

Is there any way to read the PIN set in the Windows prompt?

[image: W10Prompt]

### Question 2:

If reading the PIN is not possible, is there any other way to force PIN caching?

Comment: Can you unlock card using Windows Explorer?  There may be a driver issue with Win10  so first see if Windows will unlock card before attempting with c#.

Comment: I'm able to sign using the card and with the method I posted. The problem is when I sign multiple hashes, because the PIN doesn't get cached.

Comment: What version of SHA are you using?  See : https://www.nextofwindows.com/5-ways-to-generate-and-verify-md5-sha-checksum-of-any-file-in-windows-10

Comment: I'm using SHA1, but I don't believe that could be the problem...

Comment: There were changes made in Net 4.7 where lots of people had issues with working encryption code that stopped working.  SHA 1 may be one of these issues.  I believe 4.7 defaulted to latest 64 bit mode while older version of Net used different defaults.

Comment: The console app we used is targeted to .Net 4.6.1. If I change the code to generate a hash with SHA256, it doesnt change the behaviour.

Comment: What version of Net was used in Win 7?  Was the Win 7 a 32 bit version or 64 bit version?  The encryption issue with upgrade I know one person with Net 4.6 had issues upgrading.  Don't remember the solution.  If you change target setting make sure you do a clean build.  Did you rebuild the Pks.CmsSigner?

Comment: The console app that was tested in both Win7 and Win10 as the same build. Target .Net 4.6.1 and platform: Any CPU.

Comment: There is an X509Certificate and a X509Certificate2.  In the past I never really figured out which one should be used to be backwards compatible.  I believe that what has been causing the Net 4.7 (and maybe 4.6 issue).  I think the X509Certificate is the default that was changed to latest SHA mode.  And to be backwards compatible you need to use X509Certificate2.

Comment: X509Certificate2 extends from X509Certificate, so my guess is that any change in X509Certificate would reflect on X509Certificate2

Comment: You are working with Microsoft.  Don't assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

Only now realized this question is still without an answer although we managed to bypass the whole 'read the PIN from Windows prompt' question.

This method does not answer my first question but I'll be answering the second question.

There was a bug in the smartcard CSP provider that disabled the PIN cache for all requests to `SignHash` even though they were made in the same process.

The smartcard provider has a SDK that exposes some smartcard operations, being one of those an operation to validate the smartcard PIN.

What we ended up doing was to create a simple WPF window that requests the user's PIN and uses the SDK to validate the PIN. If it is correct we use the method that I posted in the original question to force the PIN cache:

> Another try was setting the PIN programmatically via CryptoContext, based on this answer:
>
> ```
> private void SetPinForPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate, string pin) {
>
>     if (certificate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
>     var key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
>
>     var providerHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
>     var pinBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pin);
>
>     // provider handle is implicitly released when the certificate handle is released.
>     SafeNativeMethods.Execute(() => SafeNativeMethods.CryptAcquireContext(ref providerHandle,
>                                     key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
>                                     key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
>                                     key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType,
>                                     SafeNativeMethods.CryptContextFlags.Silent));
>
>     SafeNativeMethods.Execute(() => SafeNativeMethods.CryptSetProvParam(providerHandle,
>                                     SafeNativeMethods.CryptParameter.KeyExchangePin,
>                                     pinBuffer, 0));
>     SafeNativeMethods.Execute(() => SafeNativeMethods.CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
>                                     certificate.Handle,
>                                     SafeNativeMethods.CertificateProperty.CryptoProviderHandle,
>                                     0, providerHandle));
> }
> ```

With this we are able to request the PIN only one time when signing multiple hashes until the smartcard provider fixes the bug on their side.